# Find the lengths of the semi-axes of the ellipse: $5x^2 −8xy + 5y^2 = 1$.

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Find the lengths of the semi-axes of the ellipse: $5x^2 −8xy + 5y^2 = 1$.

My Try :  I know I have to get two Perpendicular straight lines  $L_1$ and $L_2$ such that $L_1^2 + L_2^2 = 5x^2 −8xy + 5y^2 = 1$.
But I can not do it.

Can anyone please help me.

Comment: I am not sure about your background, but if you know a bit about matrix then you can do like this: By the spectral theorem, it suffices to find the reciprocals of eigenvalues of the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} 5, & -4 \\ -4 & 5 \end{pmatrix},$$ In other words, find the zeros of the characteristic polynomial $\lambda - 10\lambda + 9$ and then their reciprocals are the lengths of the semi-axes.

Comment: Answer : $1$ , $1/3 $ @SangchulLee

Comment: Reciprocals of your Matrix is $1$ , $1/9$.@SangchulLee Correct me If  I am wrong.

Comment: Ah, we need to take square root of the reciprocal, my mistake. The catch is that the computation leads to $$ 5x^2 - 8xy + 5y^2 = \left(\frac{x+y}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2 + 9\left(\frac{x-y}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2, $$ where $1$ and $9$ are the very eigenvalues (i.e. the zeros of $\lambda^2 - 10\lambda + 9$).

Comment: Yea I got it...

Comment: I am not sure why you get a matrix of order 3, but you can always write the equation into the form $$a(x-x_0)^2 + 2b(x-x_0)(y-y_0) + c(y-y_0)^2 = 1$$ and then investigate the corresponding matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ b & c \end{pmatrix} $$

Comment: I got it..@SangchulLee